How to Combine Semantic Search with SQL Analytical Queries?
I'm creating an LLM-agent that can provide insights from a complex database. The database includes several columns of different types (datetime, numeric, and text).
For simplicity, let's assume I have a table containing information about reports with three columns: Date, Category, and Description. Let's also assume that the number of categories is indefinite.
For text-related queries, semantic search has me covered. For analytical queries, such as filtering data for a time range, I could use text-to-SQL or an agent.
My problem arises when facing queries like "How many incidents related to falling off a roof happened last year?". This requires to split the task into three sub-tasks:

filter date
find relevant reports according to the Description AND the Category (AND N columns)
sum up the results

Let me present my initial approach:
Semantic Search + SQL filtering

Filter date

Filter Category with LIKE

Semantic Search over Description


Covers more ground that using pure sql filtering, but it can still be inaccurate. My current problems are:

Problem #1: This is about something very specific: counting reports. The semantic search depends on the threshold set for the similarity/distance.

Problem #2: The Category will not be fully captured with a LIKE operation.


For Problem #2 I could add the Category to the description and leave that for the semantic search, but it might also add some noise to the similarity computation, as we can see here:
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

# LangChain Ollama embeddings

eq1 = embeddings_model.embed_query("Last night I fell off my bed when I was having a nightmare and I felt really bad")
eq2 = embeddings_model.embed_query("the other day I slipped over some ice and I fell to the ground")
eq3 = embeddings_model.embed_query("I fall down all the time.")

# Cosine similarity varies with the rest of context,

# even if all three sentences talk about falling

cosine(eq1, eq2), cosine(eq1, eq3), cosine(eq2, eq3)

> > > (0.5038163339975597, 0.6419394542874378, 0.4899502476580482)

For Problem #1 I guess it depends on the threshold for the similarity as well, but then we would be dealing with a precision/recall scenario (counting irrelevant reports vs excluding relevant reports)
How to effectively combine these techniques?
